# How to add or concatenate two or more lists row wise to create dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I want to add two or more lists/ pandas series row wise to make a dataframe, how do I do that?
for example,
***Inputs=***

```
a=[1,2,3,4]
b=[9,8,7,6]
```

(Or pandas series can be there)

***Desired output =***

```
1 2 3 4
9 8 7 6
```

Comment: Did you try `pd.DataFrame([a,b])`?

Comment: I was doing pd.DataFrame(a,b) and getting a different dataframe

Comment: Because you passed different parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create list of lists/Series and pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
L = [a,b]
df = pd.DataFrame(L)
print (df)
   0  1  2  3
0  1  2  3  4
1  9  8  7  6
```

Comment: Thanks, could you explain why do I get different dataframe when I dont put a and b in the brackets[].   pd.Dataframe(a,b) gives different result.

Comment: @lsr729 - If use `pd.DataFrame(a,b)` then it is short version of `pd.DataFrame(a,index=b)` - `a` list is converted to column and `b` to index values of one column `DataFrame`, for `pd.DataFrame([a,b])` index value is default and all values of lists are converted to rows.

Comment: What is the procedure for doing the same with pandas series instead of lists?

Comment: @lsr729 - It working same way `pd.DataFrame([a,b])` - only necessary same index values for each Series